# My grandparents are British, my mother too but not by birth

Tags: citizenship, nationality

My grandparents are British, they moved to Mexico where my mother was born, she has British nationality, and now I want to know how my brother and I can obtain it too. I want to study and live in England, but as a British citizen.

Comment: You can apply for an ancestry visa. As long as you have the documents demonstrating your grandparents' citizenship and place of birth, you should acquire it without any problems. After five years on this visa, you can apply for ILR. After one year on ILR, you can apply for citizenship. From the information you've given us, I know of no quicker way.

Comment: Are you and/or your brother minors?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, my grandparents were born in the U.K. and have all their documents, my mom was born in Mexico, but also has British nationality, she never complete the paperwork for us, but now I want to do it by myself, I am not a minor, my brother is, I am the one who wants to move there next year to study.

Comment: @VictoriaSerrato: For your brother the minor, if your mother lived for some continuous period of 3 years in the UK some time in her life before he was born, he could be registered as a British citizen. This doesn't help you unfortunately.

Comment: @ouflak ancestry visas are only available to commonwealth citizens.  Victoria appears not to qualify.